# can I add array to where clause to update_batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter `update_batch` function.

I want to pass an array as the third parameter (where clause) to `update_batch`.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

I want to do this:

```
 $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, array('title','name'));
```

So multiple where conditions added.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to overwrite the update_batch function with your own. This functionality doesn't exist in the function.

Comment: I hope the CodeIgniter team will create a multibatch insert/update method for the framework. For me the update batch method for 1 index is 1600% faster then updating the database line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating your method for batch update in your model Test_model for example because Codeigniter does not supports multiple where condition in native update_batch, so example below:

```
public function update_batch_custom($table_name, $data, $indexes) {
    if (empty($data) || empty($indexes)){
        return 'Data or indexes must not be empty';
    }

    $db = $this->load->database('test_db', TRUE);
    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $table_name . ' SET ' . "\n";

    //columns on which is done actual update
    $columns = [];
    foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $indexes)){
            $columns[] = $key;
        }
    }

    /*
     * forming WHEN .. THEN sql parts and WHERE condition
     */
    $parts = [];
    $where = [];
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $sql_part = ' WHEN (';
            foreach ($indexes as $index) {
                 $sql_part .=  $index . '= \''.$row[$index] . '\' AND ';
                 $where[$index][] = $row[$index];
            }

            $sql_part = substr($sql_part, 0, -4);
            $sql_part .= ') THEN \'' . $row[$column] . '\'';
            $parts[$column][] = $sql_part;
        }
    }

    /*
     * connecting WHEN .. THEN parts for each column to be updated
     */
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $sql .= $column .'= CASE ';
        foreach ($parts[$column] as  $sql_part) {
            $sql .= $sql_part;
        }
        $sql .= ' ELSE ' . $column . ' END,';
    }

    /*
     * adding WHERE part
     */
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
    $sql .= ' WHERE ';
    foreach ($indexes as $index) {
        if ( count($where[$index]) > 0){
            $unique_where = array_unique($where[$index]);
            $sql .= $index . ' IN (\'' . join('\',\'', $unique_where) . '\') AND ';
        }
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
    $sql .= ';';

    return $db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to update your data:

```
$this->db->update("TableName",[dataarray],[where condition array]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This **update_batch** function does not allow **WHERE** parameter, but you can try splitting it before calling the function.

Try this:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'My title' ,
        'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
        'date' => 'My date 2'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Another title' ,
        'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
        'date' => 'Another date 2'
    )
);

$this->db->where('name','My Name 2');
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

Controller:

```
$chunk1 = array_chunk($data,100);
for($i=0;$i < count($chunk1);$i++) {
   $this->upload_model->update_data($chunk1[$i],'My Name 2');
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_data($data='',$name=''){
   $this->db->where('name',$name);
   $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
}
```

Remember, my WHERE parameter is a static value.

Answer (score -3):

You could always do this:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);
$this->db->where(array('title' => 'title', 'name' => 'name'));
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Not tested.

**UPDATE** This lacks the required `where` parameter in `update_batch()`.