# Update Batch in Codeigniter with multiple WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, content-management-system

I checked the CI user guide to see how to handle `update_batch()` and it seems it accept onlt one index to match which row to be updated.

But in my instance, i need to specify two index like `lang` and `id_page` which i use as index together. such `lang=en|id_page=115` is unique so the key for the row.

Means, my where index should be `WHERE lang = $lang AND id_page = $id_page` ...

Is there any approach on batch update with multiple index?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not at the moment. You could write a new driver that extends one of the existing ones but it is probably not worth it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to update_batch()  :) but it's fine. I created a loop in php to do it seperately. Thank you.